# Successful deploy on Dokku but seeing old site

Tags: node.js, dokku

I have a Dokku server running a Node.js site at Digital Ocean. I've been updating it with new version, but suddenly, I started getting an issue with deployment. I add new files to the local repository, do a `git push dokku`. The deployment process shows all the deploy output and it completes successfully.

However, after I hard reload the site, I see the old version. A reboot of the server didn't help either. Tried recommitting an empty commit and redeploying. Nothing.

```
To 104.104.104.104:mm
   93a8f81..3d4cd32  master -> master
Marcs-MBP:mm2 marc$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Trigger notification"
[master 06094b4] Trigger notification
Marcs-MBP:mm2 marcschipperheijn$ git push dokku
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 193 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building mm from herokuish...
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  ~6.10.3
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version ~6.10.3 via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing node 6.10.3...
       Using default npm version: 3.10.10
       Resolving yarn version (latest) via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing yarn (0.24.5)...
       Installed yarn 0.24.5

-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)

-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v0.24.5
       $ node internal/scripts/preinstall
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       warning fsevents@1.0.15: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.0.15" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning "react-styled-flexboxgrid@1.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "styled-components@^1.3.1 || ^2.0.0-17".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       $ npm run build

       > react-universally@13.0.0 build /tmp/build
       > babel-node internal/scripts/build --optimize

==> Registering environment variables from: /tmp/build/.env
==> Creating an optimised bundle configuration for the "client"
       loader option has been deprecated - replace with "use"
==> Creating an optimised bundle configuration for the "server"
       Hash: 3da1352e5e8f4a5467f3
       Version: webpack 2.6.1
       Time: 156672ms
       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
       0-bbe31ddeb056e33b1f34.js   224 kB       0  [emitted]
       1-9a824b6c0e696a34878b.js  30.9 kB       1  [emitted]
       2-52dc2b15e4173a333218.js  10.2 kB       2  [emitted]
       index.js   700 kB       3  [emitted]  index
       0-bbe31ddeb056e33b1f34.js.map   216 kB       0  [emitted]
       1-9a824b6c0e696a34878b.js.map  26.8 kB       1  [emitted]
       2-52dc2b15e4173a333218.js.map  6.62 kB       2  [emitted]
       index.js.map   848 kB       3  [emitted]  index
       chunk    {0} 0-bbe31ddeb056e33b1f34.js, 0-bbe31ddeb056e33b1f34.js.map 165 kB {3} [rendered]
       [214] ./shared/SyncApp.js 2.73 kB {0} [built]
       [216] ./shared/styles/CommonStyles.js 6.44 kB {0} [built]
       [227] ./shared/resources/i8n/mm.en.js 6.06 kB {0} [optional] [built]
       [228] ./shared/resources/i8n/mm.pt.js 6.86 kB {0} [optional] [built]
       [230] ./shared/resources/react-intl/pt.js 3.55 kB {0} [optional] [built]
       [232] ./shared/utils/i8n/intl.js 405 bytes {0} [built]
       [236] ./shared/resources/i8n ^./mm..*$ 214 bytes {0} [built]
       [266] ./shared/screens/Home.js 5.32 kB {0} [built]
       [267] ./shared/screens/home/Bios.js 5.11 kB {0} [built]
       [276] ./shared/screens/index.js 244 bytes {0} [built]
       [277] ./shared/store/configureStore.js 688 bytes {0} [built]
       [278] ./shared/store/reducers.js 363 bytes {0} [built]
       [279] ./shared/styles/globalCss.js 903 bytes {0} [built]
       [280] ./shared/styles/icons.js 1.23 kB {0} [built]
       [290] ./shared/resources/react-intl ^./.*$ 202 bytes {0} [built]
       + 48 hidden modules
       chunk    {1} 1-9a824b6c0e696a34878b.js, 1-9a824b6c0e696a34878b.js.map 19.5 kB {0} [rendered]
       [223] ./shared/components/navigation/Button.js 2.32 kB {1} [built]
       [231] ./shared/utils.js 744 bytes {1} [built]
       [261] ./shared/modules/contact/ContactActionTypes.js 139 bytes {1} [built]
       [262] ./shared/modules/contact/actions/contactActions.js 1.64 kB {1} [built]
       [263] ./shared/modules/contact/forms/ContactForm.js 5.42 kB {1} [built]
       [264] ./shared/modules/forms/functions/formFunctions.js 2.54 kB {1} [built]
       [272] ./shared/screens/home/contact/Contact.js 6.61 kB {1} [built]
       [281] ./shared/utils/tapEvents.js 118 bytes {1} [built]
       chunk    {2} 2-52dc2b15e4173a333218.js, 2-52dc2b15e4173a333218.js.map 5.88 kB {0} [rendered]
       [274] ./shared/screens/home/hiring/Hiring.js 5.88 kB {2} [built]
       chunk    {3} index.js, index.js.map (index) 658 kB [entry] [rendered]
       [5] ./config/index.js 3.95 kB {3} [built]
       [14] external "app-root-dir" 42 bytes {3} [not cacheable]
       [15] external "path" 42 bytes {3} [not cacheable]
       [81] external "express" 42 bytes {3} [not cacheable]
       [90] ./server/index.js 2.54 kB {3} [built]
       [102] ./server/middleware/chatHandler.js 1.75 kB {3} [built]
       [103] ./server/middleware/clientBundle.js 346 bytes {3} [built]
       [104] ./server/middleware/errorHandlers.js 852 bytes {3} [built]
       [105] ./server/middleware/mailHandler.js 2.57 kB {3} [built]
       [106] ./server/middleware/offlinePage.js 1.22 kB {3} [built]
       [111] ./server/middleware/serviceWorker.js 414 bytes {3} [built]
       [192] external "body-parser" 42 bytes {3} [not cacheable]
       [194] external "compression" 42 bytes {3} [not cacheable]
       [204] external "http" 42 bytes {3} [not cacheable]
       [213] multi ./server/index.js 28 bytes {3} [built]
       + 218 hidden modules

       WARNING in ./shared/modules/chatbot/functions/botScript.js
       23:20-30 "export 'saveWeight' was not found in './chatAPI'

       WARNING in ./shared/modules/chatbot/functions/botScript.js
       52:20-30 "export 'saveWeight' was not found in './chatAPI'
       Hash: 4d672dace247f3f9adaf
       Version: webpack 2.6.1
       Time: 231240ms
       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
       af41be6924f9c8211166d3617d12bef2.ttf  2.83 kB          [emitted]
       2b66f705e2dd0efa798a98fe687ed86d.eot  44.4 kB          [emitted]
       69f1400361a215519d385199118a34aa.ttf  44.3 kB          [emitted]
       c556ea6e1425e6e8871741ceba9c8e53.woff  19.1 kB          [emitted]
       8197018935f2e90f1531ef6c7276da46.svg  56.4 kB          [emitted]
       59b29634fc30144bbf16015659a3ae82.ttf  24.8 kB          [emitted]
       c2c196608bf159e903b4673296c661da.woff  11.5 kB          [emitted]
       27674ea7e09f7237517b005e7ea80d22.eot  33.8 kB          [emitted]
       4829f08385300b6c1f5dca7cd92ab89b.svg    98 kB          [emitted]
       1d6e07ebbc5886e714ee7de3b3b8164f.ttf  33.6 kB          [emitted]
       cd64e229e2bdc704d4ccf4e044d613ff.woff  22.2 kB          [emitted]
       16579436549dd1128209eb991d4d2be2.eot  2.98 kB          [emitted]
       16e1c72ddad39b87b5783655262524ec.svg  4.39 kB          [emitted]
       a28f51b9d3f0a244cb74fb5fc563d5cd.svg  51.2 kB          [emitted]
       7b88ba1717fdea9a44acf5a799c1da15.woff  2.19 kB          [emitted]
       806dfbd790b070ccfe05978cb27dd5bf.eot    25 kB          [emitted]
       0-6ef6da38246c71470f5d.js   238 kB       0  [emitted]
       1-2a39e135a3423ced8910.js   240 kB       1  [emitted]
       2-44370d88514c6cec2369.js  5.24 kB       2  [emitted]
       index-57c53cba4d0af05e5966.js   131 kB       3  [emitted]  index
       0-6ef6da38246c71470f5d.js.map  1.58 MB       0  [emitted]
       1-2a39e135a3423ced8910.js.map  1.86 MB       1  [emitted]
       2-44370d88514c6cec2369.js.map  19.2 kB       2  [emitted]
       index-57c53cba4d0af05e5966.js.map   927 kB       3  [emitted]  index
       offline.html  1.77 kB          [emitted]
       sw.js  16.8 kB          [emitted]
       chunk    {0} 0-6ef6da38246c71470f5d.js, 0-6ef6da38246c71470f5d.js.map 623 kB {3} [rendered]
       [74] ./shared/SyncApp.js 3.77 kB {0} [built]
       [77] ./shared/styles/CommonStyles.js 8.04 kB {0} [built]
       [186] ./~/react-intl-redux/lib/index.js 1.85 kB {0} [built]
       [219] ./shared/utils/i8n/intl.js 750 bytes {0} [built]
       [266] ./~/react-ga/src/utils/trim.js 203 bytes {0} [built]
       [267] ./~/react-intl-redux/lib/components/IntlProvider.js 862 bytes {0} [built]
       [288] ./shared/resources/i8n ^./mm..*$ 214 bytes {0} [built]
       [388] ./shared/screens/index.js 672 bytes {0} [built]
       [389] ./shared/store/configureStore.js 1.02 kB {0} [built]
       [391] ./shared/styles/globalCss.js 938 bytes {0} [built]
       [392] ./shared/styles/icons.js 1.26 kB {0} [built]
       [631] ./~/react-ga/src/index.js 12.9 kB {0} [built]
       [633] ./~/react-ga/src/utils/format.js 421 bytes {0} [built]
       [635] ./~/react-ga/src/utils/removeLeadingSlash.js 149 bytes {0} [built]
       [650] ./~/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js 3.44 kB {0} [built]
       + 263 hidden modules
       chunk    {1} 1-2a39e135a3423ced8910.js, 1-2a39e135a3423ced8910.js.map 642 kB {0} [rendered]
       [85] ./~/redux-form/es/structure/plain/index.js 587 bytes {1} [built]
       [119] ./~/babel-runtime/helpers/createClass.js 904 bytes {1} [built]
       [120] ./~/babel-runtime/helpers/inherits.js 1.11 kB {1} [built]
       [121] ./~/babel-runtime/helpers/possibleConstructorReturn.js 542 bytes {1} [built]
       [189] ./~/redux-form/es/index.js 3.17 kB {1} [built]
       [210] ./shared/components/navigation/Button.js 3.13 kB {1} [built]
       [259] ./~/material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme.js 13 kB {1} [built]
       [260] ./~/material-ui/utils/colorManipulator.js 7.62 kB {1} [built]
       [373] ./shared/modules/contact/ContactActionTypes.js 250 bytes {1} [built]
       [374] ./shared/modules/contact/actions/contactActions.js 3.15 kB {1} [built]
       [375] ./shared/modules/contact/forms/ContactForm.js 6.44 kB {1} [built]
       [376] ./shared/modules/forms/functions/formFunctions.js 4.72 kB {1} [built]
       [384] ./shared/screens/home/contact/Contact.js 10.6 kB {1} [built]
       [393] ./shared/utils/tapEvents.js 307 bytes {1} [built]
       [609] ./~/material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider.js 2.15 kB {1} [built]
       + 376 hidden modules
       chunk    {2} 2-44370d88514c6cec2369.js, 2-44370d88514c6cec2369.js.map 8.89 kB {0} [rendered]
       [386] ./shared/screens/home/hiring/Hiring.js 8.89 kB {2} [built]
       chunk    {3} index-57c53cba4d0af05e5966.js, index-57c53cba4d0af05e5966.js.map (index) 349 kB [entry] [rendered]
       [0] external {"root":"React","commonjs2":"react","commonjs":"react","amd":"react"} 42 bytes {3} [not cacheable]
       [7] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {3} [built]
       [8] ./~/react-async-component/commonjs/index.js 851 bytes {3} [built]
       [16] ./client/index.js 3.94 kB {3} [built]
       [17] ./~/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js 24.4 kB {3} [built]
       [20] ./shared/components/widgets/Loading.js 1.99 kB {3} [built]
       [22] external {"root":"ReactDOM","commonjs2":"react-dom","commonjs":"react-dom","amd":"react-dom"} 42 bytes {3} [not cacheable]
       [23] ./shared/Helmet.js 5.88 kB {3} [built]
       [31] ./client/components/ReactHotLoader.js 688 bytes {3} [built]
       [32] ./client/polyfills/index.js 769 bytes {3} [built]
       [33] ./client/registerServiceWorker.js 1.66 kB {3} [built]
       [34] ./shared/App.js 2.42 kB {3} [built]
       [42] ./.modernizrrc 1.45 kB {3} [built]
       [45] ./~/react-async-bootstrapper/commonjs/index.js 640 bytes {3} [built]
       [73] multi regenerator-runtime/runtime ./client/index.js 40 bytes {3} [built]
       + 59 hidden modules

       WARNING in duplicate-package-checker:
       <prop-types>
       15.5.7 ./~/prop-types
       15.5.10 ./~/react-redux/~/prop-types

       Child __offline_serviceworker:
       Asset     Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
       __offline_serviceworker  7.38 kB       0  __offline_serviceworker
       chunk    {0} __offline_serviceworker (__offline_serviceworker) 17.5 kB [entry] [rendered]
       [0] ./~/offline-plugin/empty-entry.js 0 bytes {0} [built]
       [1] ./~/offline-plugin/lib/misc/sw-loader.js?json=%7B%22data_var_name%22%3A%22__wpo%22%2C%22loaders%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22cacheMaps%22%3A%5B%5D%7D!./~/offline-plugin/empty-entry.js 17.5 kB {0} [built]
       Child html-webpack-plugin for "offline.html":
       Asset    Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
       offline.html  657 kB       0  
       chunk    {0} offline.html 653 kB [entry] [rendered]
       [1] ./~/fbjs/lib/warning.js 2.1 kB {0} [built]
       [3] ./~/object-assign/index.js 2.11 kB {0} [built]
       [12] ./~/react/lib/React.js 3.32 kB {0} [built]
       [43] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponent.js 4.61 kB {0} [built]
       [45] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
       [74] ./shared/components/HTML/index.js 2.05 kB {0} [built]
       [75] ./~/react-dom/server.js 65 bytes {0} [built]
       [76] ./~/babel-loader/lib!./internal/webpack/withServiceWorker/offlinePageTemplate.js 6.51 kB {0} [built]
       [92] ./~/prop-types/index.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
       [114] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMServer.js 735 bytes {0} [built]
       [118] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js 3.5 kB {0} [built]
       [158] ./~/react/lib/ReactChildren.js 6.19 kB {0} [built]
       [159] ./~/react/lib/ReactClass.js 26.9 kB {0} [built]
       [160] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMFactories.js 5.53 kB {0} [built]
       [167] ./~/react/lib/onlyChild.js 1.34 kB {0} [built]
       + 154 hidden modules
       Done in 355.57s.

-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)

-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Releasing mm (dokku/mm:latest)...
-----> Deploying mm (dokku/mm:latest)...
-----> Attempting to run scripts.dokku.predeploy from app.json (if defined)
-----> App Procfile file found (/home/dokku/mm/DOKKU_PROCFILE)
-----> DOKKU_SCALE file found (/home/dokku/mm/DOKKU_SCALE)
=====> web=1
-----> Attempting pre-flight checks
       For more efficient zero downtime deployments, create a file CHECKS.
       See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/zero-downtime-deploys/ for examples
       CHECKS file not found in container: Running simple container check...
-----> Waiting for 10 seconds ...
-----> Default container check successful!
-----> Running post-deploy
=====> renaming container (1fd3a69773f6) hungry_hopper to mm.web.1
-----> Configuring *.mysite.com.br...(using built-in template)
-----> Configuring mysite.com.br...(using built-in template)
-----> Creating http nginx.conf
-----> Running nginx-pre-reload
       Reloading nginx
-----> Setting config vars
       DOKKU_APP_RESTORE: 1
-----> Attempting to run scripts.dokku.postdeploy from app.json (if defined)
-----> Shutting down old containers in 60 seconds
=====> a5781b05b65c4e33fdcacdcc09b9bf76aeec0bd1c0301c17ea7f864723b5ac74
=====> Application deployed:
       http://*.mysite.com.br
       http://mysite.com.br

To 104.104.104.104:mm
   3d4cd32..06094b4  master -> master
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tried many things, including changing swap size and various redeploys. But I keep getting the old crap!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a Cloudflare caching issue. I had to manually purge the cache to get the new version to show. Who knew that Cloudflare would ignore a hard reload?